# can't install react-dom/test-utils via npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, jestjs

I've added two libraries to my `package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "react-dom/test-utils": "*",
    "react-test-renderer/shallow": "*"
  },
```

as suggested by [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html) to be compliant with version 16 of `react` ecosystem.

After running `npm install --verbose` I got this:

```
18 verbose node v8.5.0
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
21 error Invalid package name "react-dom/test-utils": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
22 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Also trying to install it as `devDependency` via **cli** gives this error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/react-dom/test-utils.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

**How can I solve this to have those packages available for referencing in the code?**

Comment: the things you call packages could not be packages, they **cannot be named like that**. Npm packages cannot contain slash in the name unless it is a scopes package starting from `@` symbol

Comment: @smnbbrv so how can I use something like `react-dom/test-utils` in the import statement them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `react-dom` as a dependency: `npm install --save react-dom`

When you import `react-dom/test-utils` it means: *import from the `test-utils` folder/file which is in the `react-dom` package*.